# How to run a file Javascript and get the output in Node.js console in Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

Is possible in VS IDE exec a file javascript and get the output result in the console Node.js that is inside of the VS?
As Visual Studio Code has a extension Node called "Node Exec" and as with it is possible just pressing F8 exec a script javascript and get the result in the Nodejs console like this.

[image]

I was wondering, Visual Studio IDE have a similar function or plugin? I mean, pressing or exec some button get the result in the console Nodejs?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the project Add `New Item...` -> `Javascript Unit Test File`. Place your code inside the first exported test. Bring up the Test Explorer, expand the root node, then right click the first child (your code) and select Debug. `console.log` will get written to the output window.
[Console.log shown in output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtrCX.png)